# Android camera zoom

Tags: android, camera, zooming

I developed a camera application that takes a picture, stores it to cache, then loads it
to a server. Everything works perfect. However, when I went to test it on a real phone, I noticed that zooming the camera crashing the app. I have spent 2 weeks trying to get the zoom to work and researching it. I have tried setOnZoomListener, isSmoothZoomSupported etc.
however, no matter what I do, I can't find a way to implement the zoom feature in the app without it crashing. Any point in the right direction to put this together would save my sanity!! Thank you so much in advance!!!!!

Comment: can you provide the log from adb?

Comment: I think it would be easier for us to analyze your problem if you could give us your logs and part of your source code.

Answer (score 2):

The zoom feature of mobile camera is digital zoom not the optical zooming.
So, the zooming is dependent on the camera hardware.

try to get the max zoom value of the camera by using `Camera.Parameters.getMaxZoom()`
if this method returns zoom value>1 then you are able to zoom the picture preview.
And this is hardware dependent. So, some devices may support some may not.

thanks
Vikash